# How to create a “View” user in Ubuntu? or live custom image?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, users

@Edited

Hello everybody,

I'm trying to build a small remote access solution using a computer with Ubuntu 18.04 installed and the objective is to create a solution plug-and-play, to access remote machines we have in our business.

The goal is have a computer with 2 users: `Admin` and `remote-access`.

The user `Admin` needs to have all system permissions, to `create`, `edit`, `write`, `read`, and so on...

The user `remote-access` will be used as "Automatically Logon" in the system but this user just need to have `read` access in the operational system, he will not be able to create, or edit files, only read them.

After that, we gonna install some remote applications like VNC and redirect the port to another computer that will be connected via Ethernet cable using `192.168.x.x`, but it is another process...

This will be used for virus protection, cause other users will access this computer trough the internet using the `remote-access` user, and they only can navigate in folders.

In above was my first idea, the second one, is to create a live custom image from linux, with softwares that I want and so on...

My question is: How to create the `remote-access` user and remove all that permissions?

Hope everybody understood my question.
Thanks and advanced.

Comment: You want a user who can't modify _any_ files? Not even their own ones? I don't think that can be done. Isn't it enough to have a regular guest user who can only modify things in their home directory? You need _some_ file reading capability just to log in.

Comment: There should be a third user. The Admin user needs to be split into one that can do system admin stuff (in Linux, `root`) and a normal user who can only write their `$HOME`.

Comment: You could reset the home folder of a user upon logout and/or reboot or overlay a new file system (possible but more difficult). It can certainly be done.

Comment: Sorry guys, in my text I wrote that `user` was not able to read, but the only permission the `user` must have is read only.

Comment: @Ned64 sorry, could you explain a little bit more about this?

Comment: @Ned64 is there a way to reset all system files when I startup the operational system? A way that I can make my initial configs, install some programs and blablabla and when somebody edit something or create a file, it automatically delete next time I log on?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what the final objective is here. there is no reason to block any user from writing _globally_. And I doubt it would be possible since there are many, many actions that require data to be written to certain files. The good news is that it is almost certainly not what you actually need. So if you explain what the final objective is, we should be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: @LucasGomes Yes, you can reset the system. By far the easiest way is by using VMs. Please let us know, though: Do you really require a user who can modify system files? A normal Linux user cannot - except indirectly the system logs where one can see who logged in etc.. So: Do you really need to reset system data? Also: Does the View User need to log in to the actual machine or could you use a virtual machine (requires co-operation by the View User)?

Comment: Thank you, I have changed my question, hope it is such easier to understand.